# jQuery IIS 6 Not working correctly

Tags: jquery, iis, windows-server-2003

Hey guys, I am using a Windows 2003 Server 32Bit running IIS 6. My problem is that my jQuery doesn't seem to be working properly. I have a script that loads boxes on top of an image. It loads the image fine, using jQuery, but it wont load the boxes. Now its not the script as far I can tell no debug errors come up, and if I upload the script to my server running Centos, and Apache it works just fine. It also works just fine if I load in my local machine using my browser. Any ideas on what is actually going on and how I can fix this? If you need any additional details please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is client-side, so it has nothing to do (directly) with your server. What could differ is the way you are pulling the information out of your server, i.e. the server-side pages, (say PHP) or the way your server responds to any AJAX query you may do. Try running the AJAX query by hand, for example using firebug's "net" tab.

But I doubt it is specifically-IIS6 related: more probably it is windows/linux differences, for example case sensitive file paths.

Comment: Well it seems that its returning a 405 error when I try and call that. I dont have form wrapped around my code, so I dont know what to do to fix this problem. I read up on 405 error on iis 6 and cant figure out what to do about. Perhaps you have a idea?

Comment: Have you tried to copy the URL of the request, and then manually run it in a regular browser? IIS may give you some more info about the error...

Comment: it loads just fine when I load in my browser, its when a POST method that causes the error.